# constexpr math Vector class

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, coordinate-system, c++17

I am currently playing a bit around. While the current compiler starts to finally release the `c++17` standard implementations, I am trying to create a mathematical vector class, with variable dimensions, which are stored in an `std::array`. This dimensions can be specified via template parameter.

The other requirement (beside the dynamic dimensions) is the usage of `constexpr`. I want to be able to use this in compile time expressions; this is the reason why I avoid the `std algorithms`. They are unluckily not declared `constexpr`, which is a shame, imo...
But ok, either way; here is my implementation.

Some words before you start reading:
I will implement all vector algorithms (like length, normalize, etc.) as free functions. I don't want to bloat my class with that.
Second, I like `getter` and `setter`. I know, I could simply return a reference to my internal values, but I really don't like that. That's simply a matter of taste.
Last but not least, the free operators like +, -, etc are implemented in the inherited structs; That are just some simple helper classes, thus I think it isn't necessary to post them here.

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>
#include "operators/compare.hpp"
#include "operators/arithmetic.hpp"

/*!
 * \class   Vector
 *
 * \brief   A dynamic dimensional vector class. It provides access via the operator [], and for common dimensions,
 *          getters and setters (e.g. getX(), setX()).
 *          
 *          It provides (inherited) arithmetic functions for both, Vector<T, DIM> and T. Look at the specific struct documentations
 *          to get more details.
 *          
 * \tparam  T   Generic type parameter. Must be an arithmetic type.
 * \tparam  DIM Number of dimensions.
 */
template<class T, std::size_t DIM>
class Vector :
    operators::Equal<Vector<T, DIM>>,
    operators::Plus<Vector<T, DIM>>,
    operators::Minus<Vector<T, DIM>>,
    operators::Arithmetic2<Vector<T, DIM>, T>
{
private:
    static_assert(DIM > 0, "DIM must be greater than 0.");
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, "T must be an arithmetic type.");

public:
    enum class CommonDimensions
    {
        x = 0,
        y,
        z
    };

    /*!
     * \brief   default constructor
     */
    constexpr Vector() noexcept = default;

    /*!
    * \brief    copy constructor
    */
    constexpr Vector(const Vector&) noexcept = default;

    /*!
    * \brief    move constructor
    */
    constexpr Vector(Vector&&) noexcept = default;

    /*!
    * \brief    copy-assignment operator.
    *
    * \return   A reference of this object.
    */
    constexpr Vector& operator =(const Vector&) noexcept = default;

    /*!
    * \brief    move-assignment operator.
    *
    * \return   A reference of this object.
    */
    constexpr Vector& operator =(Vector&&) noexcept = default;

    /*!
     * \brief   template constructor
     *          
     * \details Variadic template constructor for direct access on the underlaying std::array.
     * \remark  The enable_if is used to SFINAE this constructor for copy or move purposes.
     *
     * \tparam  Args    Type of the arguments.
     * \param   _args   Arguments for initialising the underlaying std::array.
     */
    template <class... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<!(sizeof...(Args) == 1 && std::is_same_v<std::common_type_t<Args...>, Vector<T, DIM>>)>>
    constexpr explicit Vector(Args&&... _args) noexcept :
    m_Values{ std::forward<Args>(_args)... }
    {
    }

    /*!
     * \brief   Gets the value at the passed index.
     *          
     * \remark  This function doesn't perform any out-of-bound check, thus it is undefined
     *          behavior to pass an invalid index [0, DIM).
     * \tparam  Index   Type of the index.
     * \param   _index  Index of value.
     *
     * \return  The result of the operation.
     */
    template <class Index>
    constexpr T operator [](Index _index) const noexcept
    {
        std::size_t index = 0;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Index, CommonDimensions>)
            index = static_cast<std::size_t>(_index);
        else
            index = _index;

        assert(0 <= index && index < DIM);
        return m_Values[index];
    }

    /*!
     * \brief   Sets the value at the passed index.
     *
     * \remark  This function doesn't perform any out-of-bound check, thus it is undefined
     *          behavior to pass an invalid index [0, DIM).
     * \tparam  Index   Type of the index.
     * \tparam  U       must be implicit convertible to T.
     * \param   _index  Index of value.
     * \param   _val    The value.
     */
    template <class Index, typename U>
    constexpr void set(Index _index, U&& _val) noexcept
    {
        std::size_t index = 0;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Index, CommonDimensions>)
            index = static_cast<std::size_t>(_index);
        else
            index = _index;

        assert(0 <= index && index < DIM);
        m_Values[index] = std::forward<U>(_val);
    }

    /*!
     * \brief   Gets the dimensions
     *
     * \return  The dimensions.
     */
    constexpr std::size_t getDimensions() const noexcept
    {
        return DIM;
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    gets X value
    *
    * \tparam   Index   This is a little trick to make the std::enable_if a dependent name. Do not pass any other type than the default one.
    * \return   Returns value of X.
    */
    template <typename Index = std::size_t, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::greater<Index>()(DIM, static_cast<Index>(CommonDimensions::x))>>
    constexpr decltype(auto) getX() const noexcept
    {
        return (*this)[CommonDimensions::x];
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    sets X value
    *
    * \tparam   U       must be implicit convertible to T
    * \tparam   Index   This is a little trick to make the std::enable_if a dependent name. Do not pass any other type than the default one.
    * \param    _value  The value.
    */
    template <typename U, typename Index = std::size_t, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::greater<Index>()(DIM, static_cast<Index>(CommonDimensions::x))>>
    constexpr void setX(U&& _value) noexcept
    {
        set(CommonDimensions::x, std::forward<U>(_value));
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    gets Y value
    *
    * \remark   This function will be available only, if this Vector has 2 or more dimensions.
    * \tparam   Index   This is a little trick to make the std::enable_if a dependent name. Do not pass any other type than the default one.
    * \return   Returns value of Y.
    */
    template <typename Index = std::size_t, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::greater<Index>()(DIM, static_cast<Index>(CommonDimensions::y))>>
    constexpr decltype(auto) getY() const noexcept
    {
        return (*this)[CommonDimensions::y];
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    sets Y value
    *
    * \remark This function will be available only, if this Vector has 2 or more dimensions.
    *
    * \tparam   U       must be implicit convertible to T
    * \tparam   Index   This is a little trick to make the std::enable_if a dependent name. Do not pass any other type than the default one.
    * \param    _value  The value.
    */
    template <typename U, typename Index = std::size_t, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::greater<Index>()(DIM, static_cast<Index>(CommonDimensions::y))>>
    constexpr void setY(U&& _value) noexcept
    {
        set(CommonDimensions::y, std::forward<U>(_value));
    }

    /*!
     * \brief   gets Z value
     *
     * \remark  This function will be available only, if this Vector has 3 or more dimensions.
     * \tparam  Index   This is a little trick to make the std::enable_if a dependent name. Do not pass any other type than the default one.
     * \return  Returns value of Z.
     */
    template <typename Index = std::size_t, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::greater<Index>()(DIM, static_cast<Index>(CommonDimensions::z))>>
    constexpr decltype(auto) getZ() const noexcept
    {
        return (*this)[CommonDimensions::z];
    }

    /*!
     * \brief   sets Z value
     *          
     * \remark This function will be available only, if this Vector has 3 or more dimensions.
     *
     * \tparam  U       must be implicit convertible to T
     * \tparam  Index   This is a little trick to make the std::enable_if a dependent name. Do not pass any other type than the default one.
     * \param   _value  The value.
     */
    template <typename U, typename Index = std::size_t, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::greater<Index>()(DIM, static_cast<Index>(CommonDimensions::z))>>
    constexpr void setZ(U&& _value) noexcept
    {
        set(CommonDimensions::z, std::forward<U>(_value));
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    member wise addition
    *
    * \param    _other  The other.
    *
    * \return   A reference of this object.
    */
    constexpr Vector& operator +=(const Vector& _other) noexcept
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < DIM; ++i)
            m_Values[i] += _other.m_Values[i];
        return *this;
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    member wise subtraction
    *
    * \param    _other  The other.
    *
    * \return   A reference of this object.
    */
    constexpr Vector& operator -=(const Vector& _other) noexcept
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < DIM; ++i)
            m_Values[i] -= _other.m_Values[i];
        return *this;
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    member wise addition
    *
    * \param    _val    The value.
    *
    * \return   A reference of this object.
    */
    constexpr Vector& operator +=(const T& _val) noexcept
    {
        for (auto& el : m_Values)
            el += _val;
        return *this;
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    member wise subtraction
    *
    * \param    _val    The value.
    *
    * \return   A reference of this object.
    */
    constexpr Vector& operator -=(const T& _val) noexcept
    {
        for (auto& el : m_Values)
            el -= _val;
        return *this;
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    member wise multiplication
    *
    * \param    _val    The value.
    *
    * \return   A reference of this object.
    */
    constexpr Vector& operator *=(const T& _val) noexcept
    {
        for (auto& el : m_Values)
            el *= _val;
        return *this;
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    member wise division
    *
    * \param    _val    The value.
    *
    * \return   A reference of this object.
    */
    constexpr Vector& operator /=(const T& _val) noexcept
    {
        for (auto& el : m_Values)
            el /= _val;
        return *this;
    }

    /*!
    * \brief    member wise modulo
    *
    * \param    _val    The value.
    *
    * \return   A reference of this object.
    */
    constexpr Vector& operator %=(const T& _val) noexcept
    {
        for (auto& el : m_Values)
            el %= _val;
        return *this;
    }

    /*!
     * \brief   Equality operator
     *
     * \details performs a member wise equality check.
     *          
     * \param   _lhs    The first instance to compare.
     * \param   _rhs    The second instance to compare.
     *  
     * \todo possibly better implementation when declared as constexpr: array equal check
     *       return _lhs.m_Values == _rhs.m_Values;
     *
     * \return  True if the parameters are considered equivalent.
     */
    friend constexpr bool operator ==(const Vector& _lhs, const Vector& _rhs) noexcept
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < DIM; ++i)
        {
            if (!(_lhs.m_Values[i] == _rhs.m_Values[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::array<T, DIM> m_Values{};
};
```

### operators arithmetic

```
namespace operators {

    /*!
     * \struct  Plus
     *
     * \brief   Single template helper struct for additions. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator +(const T&, const T&) as friend function.
     *          The inheritors must implement the operator +=(const T&, const T&) themselves.
     *
     * \tparam  T   Generic type parameter.
     */
    template <class T>
    struct Plus
    {
        /*!
         * \brief   Addition operator.
         *
         * \param   _lhs    The first value.
         * \param   _rhs    A value to add to it.
         *
         * \return  The result of the operation.
         */
        friend constexpr T operator +(const T& _lhs, const T& _rhs)
        {
            T tmp(_lhs);
            tmp += _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Minus
    *
    * \brief    Single template helper struct for subtractions. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator -(const T&, const T&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator -=(const T&, const T&) themselves.
    *
    * \tparam   T   Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T>
    struct Minus
    {
        /*!
         * \brief   Subtraction operator.
         *
         * \param   _lhs    The first value.
         * \param   _rhs    A value to subtract from it.
         *
         * \return  The result of the operation.
         */
        friend constexpr T operator -(const T& _lhs, const T& _rhs)
        {
            T tmp(_lhs);
            tmp -= _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Multiply
    *
    * \brief    Single template helper struct for multiplications. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator *(const T&, const T&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator *=(const T&, const T&) themselves.
    *
    * \tparam   T   Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T>
    struct Multiply
    {
        /*!
         * \brief   Multiplication operator.
         *
         * \param   _lhs    The first value to multiply.
         * \param   _rhs    The second value to multiply.
         *
         * \return  The result of the operation.
         */
        friend constexpr T operator *(const T& _lhs, const T& _rhs)
        {
            T tmp(_lhs);
            tmp *= _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Divide
    *
    * \brief    Single template helper struct for divisions. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator /(const T&, const T&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator /=(const T&, const T&) themselves.
    *
    * \tparam   T   Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T>
    struct Divide
    {
        /*!
         * \brief   Division operator.
         *
         * \param   _lhs    The numerator.
         * \param   _rhs    The denominator.
         *
         * \return  The result of the operation.
         */
        friend constexpr T operator /(const T& _lhs, const T& _rhs)
        {
            T tmp(_lhs);
            tmp /= _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Modulo
    *
    * \brief    Single template helper struct for modulo. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator %(const T&, const T&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator %=(const T&, const T&) themselves.
    *
    * \tparam   T   Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T>
    struct Modulo
    {
        /*!
         * \brief   Modulus operator.
         *
         * \param   _lhs    The numerator.
         * \param   _rhs    The denominator.
         *
         * \return  The result of the operation.
         */
        friend constexpr T operator %(const T& _lhs, const T& _rhs)
        {
            T tmp(_lhs);
            tmp %= _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Arithmetic
    *
    * \brief    Single template helper struct for all arithmetic operations. Look at the inherited classes for more details.
    *
    * \tparam   T   Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T>
    struct Arithmetic :
        Plus<T>,
        Minus<T>,
        Multiply<T>,
        Divide<T>
    {
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Plus2
    *
    * \brief    Multi template helper struct for additions. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator +(const T1&, const T2&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator +=(const T1&, const T2&) themselves.
    * \remark   Because lack of consistency, the reversed operator +=(const T2&, const T1&) isn't implemented by this struct. If you need it, you either have to provide it by yourself
    *           or inherit Plus2<T2, T1>.
    *
    * \tparam   T1  Generic type parameter.
    * \tparam   T2  Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T1, class T2>
    struct Plus2
    {
        /*!
        * \brief    Addition operator.
        *
        * \param    _lhs    The first value.
        * \param    _rhs    A value to add to it.
        *
        * \return   The result of the operation.
        */
        friend constexpr T1 operator +(const T1& _lhs, const T2& _rhs)
        {
            T1 tmp(_lhs);
            tmp += _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Minus2
    *
    * \brief    Multi template helper struct for subtractions. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator -(const T1&, const T2&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator -=(const T1&, const T2&) themselves.
    * \remark   Because lack of consistency, the reversed operator -=(const T2&, const T1&) isn't implemented by this struct. If you need it, you either have to provide it by yourself
    *           or inherit Minus2<T2, T1>.
    *
    * \tparam   T1  Generic type parameter.
    * \tparam   T2  Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T1, class T2>
    struct Minus2
    {
        /*!
        * \brief    Subtraction operator.
        *
        * \param    _lhs    The first value.
        * \param    _rhs    A value to subtract from it.
        *
        * \return   The result of the operation.
        */
        friend constexpr T1 operator -(const T1& _lhs, const T2& _rhs)
        {
            T1 tmp(_lhs);
            tmp -= _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Multiply2
    *
    * \brief    Multi template helper struct for multiplications. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator *(const T1&, const T2&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator *=(const T1&, const T2&) themselves.
    * \remark   Because lack of consistency, the reversed operator *=(const T2&, const T1&) isn't implemented by this struct. If you need it, you either have to provide it by yourself
    *           or inherit Multiply2<T2, T1>.
    *
    * \tparam   T1  Generic type parameter.
    * \tparam   T2  Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T1, class T2>
    struct Multiply2
    {
        /*!
        * \brief    Multiplication operator.
        *
        * \param    _lhs    The first value to multiply.
        * \param    _rhs    The second value to multiply.
        *
        * \return   The result of the operation.
        */
        friend constexpr T1 operator *(const T1& _lhs, const T2& _rhs)
        {
            T1 tmp(_lhs);
            tmp *= _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Divide2
    *
    * \brief    Multi template helper struct for divisions. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator /(const T1&, const T2&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator /=(const T1&, const T2&) themselves.
    * \remark   Because lack of consistency, the reversed operator /=(const T2&, const T1&) isn't implemented by this struct. If you need it, you either have to provide it by yourself
    *           or inherit Divide2<T2, T1>.
    *
    * \tparam   T1  Generic type parameter.
    * \tparam   T2  Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T1, class T2>
    struct Divide2
    {
        /*!
        * \brief    Division operator.
        *
        * \param    _lhs    The numerator.
        * \param    _rhs    The denominator.
        *
        * \return   The result of the operation.
        */
        friend constexpr T1 operator /(const T1& _lhs, const T2& _rhs)
        {
            T1 tmp(_lhs);
            tmp /= _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Modulo2
    *
    * \brief    Multi template helper struct for modulo. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator %(const T1&, const T2&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator %=(const T1&, const T2&) themselves.
    * \remark   Because lack of consistency, the reversed operator %=(const T2&, const T1&) isn't implemented by this struct. If you need it, you either have to provide it by yourself
    *           or inherit Modulo2<T2, T1>.
    *
    * \tparam   T1  Generic type parameter.
    * \tparam   T2  Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T1, class T2>
    struct Modulo2
    {
        /*!
        * \brief    Modulus operator.
        *
        * \param    _lhs    The numerator.
        * \param    _rhs    The denominator.
        *
        * \return   The result of the operation.
        */
        friend constexpr T1 operator %(const T1& _lhs, const T2& _rhs)
        {
            T1 tmp(_lhs);
            tmp %= _rhs;
            return tmp;
        }
    };

    /*!
    * \struct   Arithmetic2
    *
    * \brief    Multi template helper struct for all arithmetic operations. Look at the inherited classes for more details.
    *
    * \tparam   T1  Generic type parameter.
    * \tparam   T2  Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T1, class T2>
    struct Arithmetic2 :
        Plus2<T1, T2>,
        Minus2<T1, T2>,
        Multiply2<T1, T2>,
        Divide2<T1, T2>
    {
    };
} // namespace operators
```

### operators equal

```
namespace operators {

    /*!
    * \struct   Equal
    *
    * \brief    Single template helper struct for compare equal. Provides the inheritor with an implementation of operator !=(const T&, const T&) as friend function.
    *           The inheritors must implement the operator ==(const T&, const T&) themselves.
    *
    * \tparam   T   Generic type parameter.
    */
    template <class T>
    struct Equal
    {
        /*!
         * \brief   Inequality operator
         *
         * \param   _lhs    The first instance to compare.
         * \param   _rhs    The second instance to compare.
         *
         * \return  True if the parameters are not considered equivalent.
         */
        friend constexpr bool operator !=(const T& _lhs, const T& _rhs)
        {
            return !(_lhs == _rhs);
        }
    };
} // namespace operators
```

### simple use-cases

```
constexpr Vector<int, 2> getVector()
{
    Vector<int, 2> v(2);    // initializes only x with 2
    Vector<int, 2> p(1, 2);// inits x with 1 and y with 2
    v.setX(2);
    v.setY(2);
    v += v;
    v -= v;
    v += 5;
    v -= 3;
    v *= 10;
    v /= 2;
    v %= 2;

    auto t = v + 1;             // copy construction
    v = std::move(t);           // move assign

    auto x = v * 6;             // move construction
    auto d = v.getDimensions();
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr Vector<int, 2> vec(1, 2);
    auto x = vec.getX();
    auto y = vec.getY();

    constexpr auto v(getVector());    // move construction
    if constexpr (vec == v)
        x = v.getX();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are `operators::Plus` and the like? Why does functionality need to be inherited? That could make sense if you are planning also a matrix class, but if you do you might want to make the vector a specialization of the matrix.

Comment: Also: vector addition is vector addition, have never seen it done any other way. The "element-wise" specification is not necessary.

Comment: @chrisluengo vector modification by scalar is common case. like I said in the introduction, the inheritance of the operators is just a way, to remove the bloat out of the class. It is inspired by boost operators. They just implement the +, -, *, / and % operator for the passed template types.

Comment: I meant the vector+vector operation. It's the normal addition.

Comment: Please could you add the missing parts `namespace operators`, various `#include` lines, etc.  If you have (or could create) a short test program that shows how one would use the class, then that would also be worth adding to the question.

Comment: I rly don't know, why it is that interesting to see my operators; but ok, here it is. Added some simple use-cases which all will be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Why is it interesting?  Because the code *won't compile* without them!

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What follows is an unstructured brain-dump; sorry for not giving this more detailed analysis.

I think that the X, Y and Z accessors add clutter to the class, and I would consider writing subclasses or wrappers of `Vector<T, 2>` and `Vector<T, 3>` to provide those.  That's probably just a judgement call.

Can `std::rel_ops` take the place of the `Equals<>` mix-in class?  They seem to do the same thing, but one is provided and well-known.  If not, then also consider `Boost.operators` (if Boost is acceptable to you).

Why inherit from `Plus` and `Minus` individually, but from `Arithmetic2` *en bloc*?  And is it intentional that `Arithmetic2` doesn't inherit from `Modulo2`, or is that an oversight?

Multiplication by a scalar should be commutative: if `v * 6` is legal, why not `6 * v`?

The `std::enable_if` on the template constructor looks too constrained - I think you should be able to `std::enable_if_t<std::is_assignable<T,std::common_type_t<Args...>>`, but maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to do here.  I'd have expected a simple

```
template<typename... Args>
constexpr explicit Vector(Args&&... args) noexcept
    : m_Values{{std::forward<Args>(args)...}}
```

and rely on `std::array` rejecting ill-formed construction.

Usually `operator[]` returns a reference, at least for the non-`const` overload (but that appears to be missing).  Instead of a template, it's probably better to provide overloads for `std::size_t` and `CommonDimensions` arguments - or a conversion from the latter to the former.

Also, `operator[]` conventionally doesn't check array bounds - bounds-checking interfaces are called `at()` in the standard library, and it makes sense to follow the same conventions.

Consider making a `Vector` act as a standard container - provide `size()` as a synonym (or replacement) for `getDimensions()`.  It may well be worth exposing some public typedefs for `value_type` and similar.

It's a shame that `std::array::operator==` can't propagate `constexpr`/`noexcept` from its `value_type::operator==`, or we'd be able to write

```
constexpr bool operator ==(const Vector& other) const noexcept
{
    return m_Values == other.m_Values;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My operator structs do almost the same as `boost::operators` (but mine are `constexpr`). I don't wanted to add this type of dependency to my privat lib, thus I decided to implement this myself. I didn't know `std::rel_ops`, but they don't seem to be usable in an elegant way.
The missing `Modulo(2)` for the `Arithmetic(2)` is a mistake, thanks for this!
Yeah, an overload of CommonDimensions would be a better choice than the template!

Multiplication and Addition are both commutative; shall I add those operators? Is it practical? Because `-`, `/` and `%` aren't...

Comment: Most of your questions in the comment are choices - I've made observations, but I'm consciously shying away from recommendations.  Use your judgement.  If you think that unary `-` would make sense, then I'd suggest implementing `T - Vector` operator.  TBH, I don't see a use case for adding a `T` to every element (and I like my utility classes to be informed by how I need to use them).  N.B. I'm not saying it has *no* value; just that I'm ignorant of it.

Comment: I'm not sure why you find `std::rel_ops` inelegant - perhaps construct a new question around that?  (Is it because of constexpr?  Or is it difficulty with importing it into the right namespace for ADL to work properly?).

Comment: Be wary of suggesting `std::rel_ops`: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/7c5h80/discussion_spaceship_operator_vs_pythons_total/dpnhhdc/

Comment: @TobySpeight, Justin is right. Lets wait for three way comparison (`<=>`), it should make it in C++20.